# Check Email during Xcode UI Testing?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, ios-ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

UPDATE: Is this still possible with the new way of UI [testing with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/01-introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132)?

Can I programmatically access my email from an [iOS UI Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) script?

I want to access the signup code that my iPhone app emails to my email account.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524217/xcode-ui-testing-passwordless-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSURLSession` to make HTTP requests from within test methods. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708282/242933

Answer (score 1):

If you have a way for your device/simulator to receive the code while still in the app then you can write a script an iOS UIA script to do this.

However with the current state of the built in iOS UIA tool, you cannot access anything that is outside of your app. So basically you cannot launch your app, then launch another app (like safari) go to mail.google.com blah blah.

The closest thing to leaving your app in iOS UIA is using a function call to send your app to background for X amount of seconds.

Comment: Yes, but could I programmatically access my Gmail account from my UI Automation script?

Comment: You could if your app opens a WebView. However, if your app redirects to Safari then you cannot. You can however use `UIAHost.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` to launch an external script on the host computer that could grab the code for you.

Comment: @Braains got any ideas for the new way of UI testing with Xcode? It doesn't seem to have anything like `UIAHost.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678717/performtaskwithpathargumentstimeout-in-xctest

Comment: I'm no longer working as an automation engineer so I haven't checked the new framework out. It seems however more strictly defined than before in that it tries very hard to only let you simulate things that the user could do. Presumably the user can not send messages to a host computer without there being UI to do so. I've seen some comments about passing in launch arguments to the code so you could set your app to respond to a launch argument with known data if you need an access code. If you just need to make sure the email arrives you could script that independently and combine logs maybe?