# Xcode UI Testing passwordless authentication

Tags: authentication, xcode-ui-testing

How should I test my iPhone app's [passwordless authentication](https://medium.com/@ninjudd/passwords-are-obsolete-9ed56d483eb)?

To sign up or log in, [UI Testing in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/) needs the random code that gets emailed to me.

Comment: Maybe set up a web service to get that random code then you can enter that in your app? That's what my approach would be.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613698/check-email-during-xcode-ui-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSURLSession` to make HTTP requests from within test methods.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should run UI tests on stage/QA env and as result you can have some backdoor on stage env for UI tests, for example accept code 1111 for all users etc

Answer (score 2):

1. Add your email account to the Mail app. Make sure that Push notifications are enabled.
2. Set the notifications style for Mail to the Alerts style.
3. In your UI Tests, add the [UI interruption monitor](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCTestCase.html#//api/name/addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription:handler:) to listen for the alert from Mail, which contains the random two-factor authentication code.

Comment: Neat idea! Unfortunately, Simulator doesn't have the Mail app.

Comment: Ah, I'm testing on real devices.