# performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout in XCTest?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ios-ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

Does the new way of UI [testing with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/01-introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132) have a method like [`performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAHost/performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout)?

Ultimately, how can I [Check Email during Xcode UI Testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613698/check-gmail-from-ios-ui-automation/23645190#comment59035714_23645190)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524217/xcode-ui-testing-passwordless-authentication

Answer (score 1):

It does not. I've scraped the framework's headers to put together some [unofficial documentation](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation) and it's not present.